# mysql query doesnt work

Tags: mysql, wordpress, meta-key

I have a problem with a query in mysql.
It's from a wordpress blog and a try to set the title of each post als meta_key and meta_value

```
INSERT  `wordpress_postmeta` (`meta_id` ,`post_id` ,`meta_key` ,`meta_value`)
VALUES ( '',`ID` , _yoast_wpseo_focuskw, `wordpress_posts`.`post_title`) 
(`wordpress_posts`.`ID` , _yoast_wpseo_focuskw, `ewordpress_posts`.`post_title`)
SELECT * FROM ewordpress_posts WHERE (`wordpress_posts`.`post_status` = 'future'))
```

1. is it possible to do this in one query?
2. where is my fault?

Comment: Remember that we don't know your columns, tables, values, MySQL version, etc...

Comment: see proper [insert-select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Joem, please add the errormessage. Without the information we can`t help you

Comment: What's happen where you execute your code ?

Comment: MySQL meldet: Dokumentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`wordpress_posts`.`ID` , _yoast_wpseo_focuskw, `ewordpress_posts`.`post_title`)' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that :

```
INSERT INTO `wordpress_postmeta` (`meta_id` ,`post_id` ,`meta_key` ,`meta_value`)
SELECT '',t1.`ID` , t2._yoast_wpseo_focuskw, t1.`post_title` 
FROM ewordpress_posts t1, ekwh_wordpress_postmeta t2
WHERE `post_status` = 'future'
```

this assuming `_yoast_wpseo_focuskw` is in your table `ewordpress_posts`

Comment: There are two tables

1. ekwh_wordpress_posts

2. ekwh_wordpress_postmeta

mom... I'm looking for the fields

Comment: check edited answer , added second table if this what you want.

Comment: table1:  ekwh_wordpress_post 

table2: ekwh_wordpress_postmeta 


in table post i need the field  post_title

and copy this title to postmeta  with a new  meta_id  (autoincrement)
post_id (like post_id from table 1 post) meta_key (like post_title from table1_post) and meta_value (like post_title from table1_post)

Comment: doenst work. I only need ID and post_title from ekwh_wordpress_post